# How return multi-result (2 tables) from sql-query into Excel Worksheet?

Tags: vba

I have sql query which returne 2 tables with different structure as a result.
I nee somehow to wrote code in VBA/VSTO to get this 2 table from that sql-query.
What should i start from?
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it's possible.  You'll need to use code a bit like that below:

```
Sub ConnectionExample6()
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

   ' Open a connection by referencing the ODBC driver.
   cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
      "server=MySqlServer;uid=MyUserName;pwd=MyPassword;database=pubs"
   cnn.Open

   ' Create a Recordset by executing an SQL statement.
   Set rs = cnn.Execute("Select * From authors")

   ' Show the first author.
   MsgBox rs("au_fname") & " " & rs("au_lname")

   ' Close the connection.
   rs.Close

End Sub
```

Source is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx

Try to use this, then come back and tell us if you have problems.